# Database doesn't update/write instantly

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, microservices, amazon-rds

For context, i am making a multi-player game using nodejs and my db is postgres.
players play one by one, and i save everything in the db.
when first user plays, they can't play again, until the other player played too.

what i am doing now is having a boolean on each player in the db that says "ableToPlay" which is true, then turns to false if it's not the user's turn.

issue is when user spams the "play button" and my db is in a remote server, it takes time to update from true to false, making the user play multiple times then causes the app to crash.

I am using aws Microservices architecture so the server must be stateless.
is there any way i can save the game progress in a way where the progress is accessible to all my micro-services?

Comment: You could throttle the play button.

Comment: they could mess with the web socket connection, my app is money related, so it must be very secure

Comment: Set the flag false when you process a "play"? Don't have the DB process any more plays while the flag is false. I'm having trouble seeing where the issue is here.

Comment: Write your application correctly, using transactions correctly.  We can't say where your mistake is, as you haven't given us any relevant information. But clearly you have made one somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

How do you check the turn? Is it something:

- select turn from db
- if turn == X then
- //allow the turn
- do all the logic
- update the turn to Y
- endif

So the "do all the logic" may be called several times as several requests will get turn=X.

This is a very common problem in programming, there are several approaches you could do.

Two key observations to address:

- the same player should not do a turn twice in a row
- while one player is making the turn, the other player must wait

Easiest way it to use a transaction in the DB while the turn is happening. For example, when player X making the turn:

- start transaction
- update turn=X where turn=Y (Y is the other player)
- if update done (one record is updates)
- do all the logic
- commit the transaction

In that approach, update will wait for the previous one to finish, and the WHERE clause will make sure the same player won't do two or more turns in a row. And the transaction isolation will avoid running turn logic at the same time.

If you don't want to use the transaction, you could build a state machine, with states:

- waitingForTurnX
- makingTurnX
- waitingForTurnY
- makingTurnY

this would be a nice model to code and these transitions could be handled without transactions:

update state=makingTurnX where state=waitingForTurnX

This approach will also eliminate race condition, because in vast majority of databases, updates are atomic when it comes to a single record.

Comment: regarding your first approach, im assuming we can change the turn from X to Y only when it's X's turn, which means doing "where: turn=y" doesn't make sense cuz we know "turn" is now equaled to X,  you know i spent like 4 months making this app locally and spent around 1.5k usd on it, and now deploying  it a remote server and setting up aws and everything, it got bugg due to this db writing issue, im in total disappointment

Comment: btw, here's a staging link to the app https://betbux-frontend-omgt1jjt2-betbux-staging.vercel.app/mines

Comment: distributed systems are hard for everyone, we all get weird bugs all the time... :)